# How to decrement quarterly for this format: yyyy-Qx (2022-Q1, 2022-Q2, 2022-Q3, etc.)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[What I want to do]
By using a formula, I want to be able to increment the quarterly based date when referencing a quarterly date that's like this: 2022-Q1, 2022-Q2, 2022-Q3, 2022-Q4. However, from my understanding, there isn't a dedicated formula that can compute this conveniently.

To make this more clear, I've created a sample sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19woGGRDa-pMPAHMmP3tVMNTYfO56xwgmFx9PCg6czy0/edit#gid=0

You'll notice that, cell C4 is obtaining the quarterly date by referencing from A2, which is a dropdown list.

Now, I want D4 to reference C4 as well, however, I want it decremented by 1 quarter. So if C4 is "2022-Q4", D4 would be "2022-Q3".

[Research]
I know that you can do something similar if you used this formula: EDATE(C4,-1), which would decrement by 1 month. And I checked this website that explains about incrementing by quarter.
https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/extract-quarter-from-a-date-in-google-sheets-formula-options/
However, the challenge is that it's not in this format: 2022-Q1, which is a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this to cell `D4`:

```
=LEFT(C4,4) + IF(OR(MOD(RIGHT(C4)-1,4)=0, (RIGHT(C4, 1)-1)<0),-1,0) & "-Q"&IF(MOD(RIGHT(C4)-1,4)=0,4,MOD(RIGHT(C4)-1,4))
```

To fill up `E4` and `F4`, highlight `D4` and drag the corner of cell `D4` to `E4` and `F4`.

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### References:

- [LEFT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079?hl=en)
- [RIGHT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094087?hl=en)
- [MOD](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093497?hl=en)
- [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so much!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try in D4 and drag to the right

```
=regexextract(C4,"\d+")+if(REGEXEXTRACT(C4,"Q(\d)")-1,0,-1)&"-Q"&REGEXEXTRACT(C4,"Q(\d)")-1+if(REGEXEXTRACT(C4,"Q(\d)")-1,0,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few shorter versions:

```
=if(right(C4)="1", left(C4,4)-1, left(C4, 4)) & "-Q" & mod(right(C4)+2,4)+1
```

```
=left(C4,4)+floor(right(C4)/5-0.3) & "-Q" & mod(right(C4)+2,4)+1
```